# Eclipse error for extended class

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to create and extended class from the one bellow but I'm getting an error message from eclipse saying "Syntax error on token "{", { expected after this token"

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Ship {

protected int hull;
protected int shield;
protected Vector2 velocity;
protected int energy;
protected Texture shipTexture;
protected Vector2 position;

public Texture getShipTexture() {
    return shipTexture;
}
public void setShipTexture(Texture shipTexture) {
    this.shipTexture = shipTexture;
}

public Vector2 getPosition() {
    return position;
}
public void setPosition(Vector2 position) {
    this.position = position;
}
public int getHull() {
    return hull;
}
public void setHull(int hull) {
    this.hull = hull;
}
public int getShield() {
    return shield;
}
public void setShield(int shield) {
    this.shield = shield;
}
public Vector2 getVelocity() {
    return velocity;
}
public void setVelocity(Vector2 velocity) {
    this.velocity = velocity;
}
public int getEnergy() {
    return energy;
}
public void setEnergy(int energy) {
    this.energy = energy;
}




}
```

for this class after the first bracket:

```
public class Frigate extends Ship {

this.hull = 10;
this.shield = 10;

}
```

Is there a better way to set up "ships" with the same variables and actions but with different values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to initialize instance variables for your `Frigate`.  Place that code inside a constructor.

```
public Frigate()
{
    this.hull = 10;
    this.shield = 10;
}
```

Comment: That looks to be a good solution. Is there an easy way to explain why it needs the constructor to change those variables?

Comment: Things like `this.hull = 10;` are statements, not declarations.  Statements need to go in blocks of code, e.g. constructors and methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a constructor fir Ship that accepts the two values:

```
protected Ship(int hull, int shield) {
    this.hull = hull;
    this.shield = shield;
}
```

Then call it from the subclass:

```
public class Frigate extends Ship {
    public Frigate {
        super(10, 10);
    }
```

You should consider making Ship abstract as well, if it's just a "base" class.